# How to update the status bar in MainWindow from the Central Widget Class?

Tags: c++, qt

I have been searching for hours trying to find an hour to this question, so I am going to try to simplify it down as much as possible.

Essentially I have a Casino program I am working on. Right now I am only worrying about blackjack, but the program so far works as follows.

MainWindow Class

> Shows a welcome message with a few buttons to select which game you want. When the Blackjack button is clicked, it sets the central widget to my Blackjack Class.

Blackjack Widget Class

Here is where I am needing help. I am wanting to update the StatusBar with values from this class but I truly can't for the life of me figure out how. Here is some of the code from the program.

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_blackjackButton_clicked()
{
    Blackjack *blackjack = new Blackjack(this);
    blackjack->setPlayer(player);
    this->setCentralWidget(blackjack);
    this->setFixedSize(1600,900);
}
```

blackjack.cpp

```
void Blackjack::on_dealButton_clicked()
{

    // TODO Going to add these to the status bar
    setRegularBet(ui->spinBet->value());
    setBusterBlackjackBet(ui->spinBuster->value());
    setFortuneBet(ui->spinFortune->value());

    // Adding the 3 bets to the status bar
    QLabel *labelRegBet = new QLabel(this);
    labelRegBet->setText("Regular Bet: $" + QString::number(getRegularBet()));
}
```

The labelRegBet is what I am looking to add to the status bar.

Comment: you shouldn't update statusbar , you should update your content inside label , and put your label in statusbar, for doing this you need QTimer .

Answer (score 0):

codes that you put in question didn't help us, because it has so many dependencies on other functions and classes that you write.

As I understand from the question, you want one label in the `statusbar of mainwindow`  that you can put something in the label that should be updated.

So look at this example, I create one label that shows Time and it updates each second I think this will help you and you can use it in your program :
as you know mainwindow has by default statusBar look at this image :

[image]

I write this in mainwindow.cpp :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QLabel>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto    _timer = new QTimer;
    QLabel *lbl    = new QLabel(ui->statusbar);

    connect(_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [lbl]()
    {
        QTime time        = QTime::currentTime();
        QString Time_text = time.toString("hh : mm : ss");
        lbl->setText(Time_text);
    });

    _timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**Out put :**

[image]

**As you see I put `ui->statusbar` as a label parent .and to update it each second I use `QTimer`**

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the issue. Blackjack.cpp is a widget class. It is set as the central widget for my mainwindow.cpp class. I am trying to add the label to the status bar from the blackjack class, not the main window class

Comment: It does not matter, If you want to update the content inside the label you should use QTimer like this example, it's not important that this label is where. In my example, I update time you can update whatever you like, QTimer makes that one function repeatedly called , I use lambda function @NicholasTallarico

Comment: That's not true. I can't access the StatusBar from my blackjack class and that is the issue..

Comment: you should put all program that I can underestand what you say. I can't test what you put in question. provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: and qt has [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) for creating communication between classes, I guess you need this.